# github-actions bot spamming my github feed

Tags: github, github-actions

So I have a workflow in one of my repositories which updates my readme file every 5 mins. How do I prevent the github-actions bot spamming my feed?

Image for reference:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The feed activity appears because you're watching the repository and it's set to "All activity".

You can change it to another watch option upon your liking and it'll be gone:

[image: GitHub Screenshot]